# What's the index for relation $R$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

X is a size 8 set formed by 1,2,3,4,5

We define relation $R$ on X such that, $xRy$$\Leftrightarrow $ $x$ and $y$ sets formed from same numbers and same amount of each kind. We know the relation $R$ is already an equivalence relation
an example:
[image]

How I can approach this question? knowing there are $8^5$ possible ways to form set x,y that belong to X

Comment: In a set, $\{1,2,3\} = \{1,1,2,3\} = \{3,2,1\}$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux no there's only one 1's they need to be two 1's to match

Comment: But these are not sets.